# What subexpressions does an operator apply to if it has the highest precedence?

Tags: c++, expression, operator-precedence

```cpp
int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
bool z = a >= b || b == c && !b && !!a;
cout << z << endl;
```

I would like to know why this code prints `0`.

I don't know where to start, even though I know that `>=` has the highest precedence.
Does this mean that `a` is compared with all of `(b || b == c && !b && !!a)`, or just with `b`?

Comment: I guess it's something that prof in the university gave you as an exercise? IMHO these kind of quiz doesn't have any value from programming learning POV. You can red this section about [operators precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) and just work it piece by piece.

Comment: Though on a theoretical point on view, the question might be interesting, I would strongly discourage this kind of code as, precisely, it is hard to understand. Relying on order of evaluation and on operator precedence often leads me to mistakes...

Comment: Just add `(` and `)` to make clear what you mean. I would not let this pass a code review. And if this would be code by  my teacher that would be my answer. (And that is even before considering the implicit type conversion from int to bool)

Comment: @pptaszni -- You can add in the *what does this print?* questions I see that look like this:  `int a = 1; int b = 2;  int x = ++b + ++a + b +a; cout << x;`.  It's really a waste of a student's time if this was given as homework, when there are far more interesting and relevant aspects of C++ that should be taught..

Comment: It;s easy. Most would break on something like `a = b + c ? d & a ? e : f : g;` I call those expressions "programmer's torture"

Comment: That `>=` has higher precedence than `||` means that `x >= y || z` is `(x >= y) || z`. That is, the `>=` is evaluated before the `||`. Also, `&&` is to `||` as `*` is to `+`.

Comment: `bool z = (a >= b) || ((b == c) && (!b) && (!!a));`

Comment: In fact I totally agree with @Swift-FridayPie. Complex logical expressions like this also deserve to be put in a function with a readable name `bool z = some_readable_name(a,b,c);`. You will really help your future you as well as your collegues. AND better you get to write unit tests for that function (is it really calculating the right answer for all your a,b,c values).

Comment: BTW, `&& !!a` (i.e `a != 0`) is unneeded, `!b` -> `b == 0`, and second `or` branch implies `a < b` so `a != 0`. `bool z = (a >= b) || ((b == 0) && (c == 0));`.

Answer (score 3):

When an operator has higher precedence than a neighbouring operator, it "binds" the operands tighter; `x >= y || z` means `(x >= y) || z`.
(This makes sense since you want `a < b || c < d` to be "a is less than b, or c is less than d", not "a is less than (b or c) is less than d", which is nonsense.)

To work this one out, add parentheses from the highest precedence to the lowest.
`!` has the highest precence, so

```
a >= b || b == c && (!b) && (!(!a))
```

Next in line, the relational operator,

```
(a >= b) || b == c && (!b) && (!(!a))
```

Then equality,

```
(a >= b) || (b == c) && (!b) && (!(!a))
```

Then `&&`, which associates to the left:

```
(a >= b) || (((b == c) && (!b)) && (!(!a)))
```

And then there's only `||` left, so you don't need to do anything about it.

So you have

```
(1 >= 2) || (((2 == 3) && (!2)) && (!(!1)))
```

which is

```
(1 >= 2) || (((2 == 3) && (2 == 0)) && (!(1 == 0)))
```

which is

```
false || ((false && false) && true)
```

which is

```
false
```

Note that, since the logical operators "short-circuit", this actually evaluates as

```
(1 >= 2) || (((2 == 3) && (!2)) && (!(!1)))
false || (((2 == 3) && (!2)) && (!(!1)))
((2 == 3) && (!2)) && (!(!1))
(false && (!2)) && (!(!1))
false && (!(!1))
false
```

but since there are no side effects, the result is the same.

Comment: Re “That an operator has higher precedence means that it get evaluated first”: No, it does not. Precedence determines the structure of an expression, and the structure imposes a partial ordering on evaluation (subexpressions of an operation must be evaluated before they can be used in the operation) but not a total ordering. In `1+2 & 3*4`, `*` has higher precedence than `+`, but a compiler may evaluate `+` first.

Comment: And to be pedantic: C++ does not even have the concept of operator precedence - only associativity and what forms a valid expression - precedence is just a nice way to group the behaviour for when we are talking about the operators.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I edited in an attempt to make it more correct while staying reasonably beginner-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that `>=` has the highest precedence, but doest it means `a` is compare with this `(b || b == c && !b && !!a )` whole thing? or just `b`.

Ok, let's think. Say you have `1 * 2 + 3`. From the same precedence table you used, you can see that `*` has higher precedence than `+`. Does this mean `1` is multiplied by `2 + 3` or just `2`?